# symfony The controller must return a response FOS Rest API

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to make action like in FOSRestBundleByExample/blob.

My action:

```
    public function putManagerToMpkAction()
{
    $view = View::create();
    $view->setStatusCode(404)->setData("Error Message");
    return $view;
}
```

But i have and response:

> The controller must return a response (Object(FOS\RestBundle\View\View) given).

I have found i can change view_response_listener to true in my config, but then i have:

> Unable to find template "".

Any ideas?

Thanks
Kamil

Comment: Does your controller extend the FOSRestController?

Comment: Yes, FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do :

```
return $this->handleView($view);
```

Source : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html

Comment: After that Symfony styll are looking for template named as a method. I my method is named postManagerAction symfony are looking for vied named "postManager.twig.html".

> Unable to find template "".

Can I disable this and just return $this->handleView()?

Comment: Well, you need to have a template somehow since you are sending a response. The application can't _guess_ how you want to render your data... so you have to create a template.

Comment: But if I don't want to show anything? I just want to return status 200 if everything is OK, or json data.

Comment: Well, don't set any data then `view()->setStatusCode(200)`